# MySQL search value from textbox

Tags: php, mysql

I've been trying for several hours to search values passed from textboxes. Textboxes are *itemname*, *item description*, *unitcost* and *quantity*. In this, *unitcost* and *quantity* has two textboxes. It should search the range values. The [SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) code I have tried is:

#### [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) of textbox

```
<input name="item_search" id="item_search" value="" placeholder="" class="input-size 
search-estimateid_search search-text" type="text">
<input class="input-small" name="sunit_cost" id="sunit_cost" type="text">
<input class="input-small" name="eunit_cose" id="eunit_cost"type="text">
<input name="item_description" id="item_description" type="text">
<input class="input-small" name="squantity" id="squantity" type="text">
<input class="input-small" name="equantity" id="equantity" type="text">

$itemname = $_POST['item_name']; //Value from textbox itemname
$description = $_POST['item_description']; // "
$start_cost = $_POST['startcost']; // Range values to search in unitcost
$end_cost = $_POST['endcost']; // "
$start_quantity = $_POST['startquantity'];//Range values to search in quantity
$end_quantity = $_POST['endquantity']; // "
```

#### MySQL query

```
mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM `quotation`.`items` WHERE (CONVERT(`NAME` USING utf8) LIKE
'%$itemname%' AND CONVERT(`DESCRIPTION` USING utf8) LIKE '%$description%' AND (COST 
BETWEEN $startcost AND $endcost)AND (QTY BETWEEN $startquantity AND $endquantity));")or
die(mysql_error());
```

How do I get my code to execute even if some values are not passed from the textbox?

Comment: Can you show us some HTML?

Comment: what is the error you get ?

Comment: What does the exact query look like and does it work from the mysql command line / phpMyAdmin? And you have an sql injection problem.

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: if i give any one value for textbox i get only null as output.

Comment: The `name="something"` is what PHP receives when you submit the form so make sure your PHP matches what your HTML is giving you. So `<input type="text" name="something" />` will be accessible if you use `echo $_POST['something'];`

Comment: In the event that either the name or description inputs are blank, then you have to set the corresponding as variables as blank or exclude them from the query! Any why are you converting stuff?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try the following. If a few of your text boxes are empty then also search using a textbox that is nonempty.

```
<?php
    $condition = "WHERE ";
    if (!empty($_POST['itemname'])) {
        $condition .= "(CONVERT(`NAME` USING utf8) LIKE '".$_POST['itemname']."' AND  ";
    }
    if (!empty($_POST['item'])) {
        $condition .= "NAME ='".$_POST['item']."' AND ";
    }

    if (!empty($_POST['description'])) {
        $condition .= "CONVERT(`DESCRIPTION` USING utf8) LIKE  '".$_POST['description']."' AND  ";
    }

    if (!empty($_POST['startcost']) && !empty($_POST['endcost'])) {
         $condition .= "(COST BETWEEN '".$_POST['startcost'] ."' AND '".$_POST['endcost']."') AND  ";
    }

    if (!empty($_POST['startquantity']) && !empty($_POST['endquantity'])) {
         $condition .= "(QTY BETWEEN '".$_POST['startquantity']."' AND '".$_POST['endquantity']."') AND  ";
    }

    mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM `quotation`.`items` '".$condition."'")or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to clean it up a bit...

```
SELECT *  FROM `quotation`.`items` WHERE CONVERT(`NAME` USING utf8) LIKE 
'%$_POST[item_name]%' AND CONVERT(`DESCRIPTION` USING utf8) LIKE     
'%$_POST['item_description']%' AND COST > $_POST['startcost']
 AND COST < $_POST['endcost'])AND QTY > $_POST['startquantity'] AND
 QTY < $_POST['endquantity']
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is just a typo, but your `name` attibutes do not match at all with the variables you are trying to get from `$_POST`.

For example:

```
<input class="input-small" name="squantity" id="squantity" type="text">
```

In [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP), it would be available as:

```
$start_quantity = $_POST['squantity'];
                          ^^^^^^^^^ here
```

You would also need to build your query depending on what variables are actually set / have valid values.

You also need to switch to [PDO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#History) or [MySQLi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQLi) with prepared statements and bound variables, because now you have an [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) problem and the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You may also write a [stored procedure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure) that accepts the search terms as parameters and have the procedure concatenate different query terms if the values passed or not null or empty string.

Your procedure would look something like this:

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE `search_products`(
    IN item_name VARCHAR(50),
    IN description VARCHAR(50),
    IN start_cost decimal ,
    IN end_cost decimal,
    IN start_quantity int,
    IN end_quantity int
)
BEGIN
    set @sql = " select * from quotation.items where 0=0 ";

    if ((item_name is not null) and (item_name<>'')) then
       set @sql = concat(@sql," and NAME   like  '",item_name,"%'");
    end if;

    if ((item_name is not null) and (item_name<>'')) then
       set @sql = concat(@sql," and NAME   like  '",item_name,"%'");
    end if;

    if ((start_cost is not null) and (start_cost<>'')and (end_cost is not null) and (end_cost<>'')) then
        set @sql =concat(@sql, " and `COST` BETWEEN ", start_cost, " and ", start_cost);
    end if;

    if ((start_quantity is not null) and (start_quantity<>'')and (end_quantity is not null) and (end_quantity<>'')) then
        set @sql =concat(@sql, " and `COST` BETWEEN ", start_quantity, " and ", end_quantity);
    end if;
    PREPARE vsql FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE vsql;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE vsql;
END;
```

Then in the section of your PHP code where you would call the query, you would just call the stored procedure. This is how I usually handle queries with optional parameters.
You need to also keep an eye on the name you have to the field in order to receive those values using the post method call. The names have to be the same.